# How do I flatten a PDF file in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm running Adobe Acrobat Pro DC on Windows 10.

I scan a single page of text and save it as a PDF.  From a photo editing application (doesn't matter what it is), copy an image into the clipboard (1 inch by 2 inches is fine).  Launch Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and open the PDF.  Now do Edit > Paste and drag/size the image to some place on the page.  How do I save this as a PDF without a separate image "floating" on the page.

My objective: when the consumer of the PDF clicks on what used to be the image, the entire page is selected, not just the 1" X 2" image.

What I have tried:

1. `Tools > Print Production > Preflight > PDF fixups > Flatten annotations and form fields` and then click on `Analyze and fix`.  The result is "Flatten all annotations into page contents (1 object)" and "No problems found".  I close Adobe Acrobat.  From Explorer I confirm the file was created and that the timestamp indicates it was just created.  It is identical to the file I started with.  When I click on what was the image, only the image is selected, proving that no flattening had occurred.
2. There is a script floating around the web:

   `this.flattenPages();`

   From Adobe Acrobat: `Tools > Javascript` and then `Document JavaScripts`.

   I enter a script name, click `Add`, and enter the script.  Now what?  There is no **Run** button anywhere.  How do I run this script?
3. Printing the document to a PDF printer from within Adobe Acrobat and from within the Edge browser.  Both resulting PDF files that preserve the image as a separate object.

The Workaround:

This is really ugly, but the only way I could get what I wanted was to print the page to a color printer and then scan the freshly printed page as a PDF and replace the page giving me trouble with the freshly scanned page.

Comment: You can copy paste the 1" X 2" image directly in the scan then create pdf from it.

Answer (score 0):

Item 2 is almost there, but what you would do is open the Console (you may have to activate it first in the JavaScript tab of the Acrobat Preferences), enter

```
this.flattenPages() ;
```

then bring the cursor back onto that line and press `<Ctrl><Return>` (on Windows) or `<Cmd><Return>` (on Mac). If your keyboard has the numeric block, you may also press the `<Enter>` key there.

You might refer to [this tutorial](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console/) for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Control J opens console.
In the console (lower left dialog box) type
flattenPages();
tap enter

That's it.  It flattens the active PDF file.
Please note that it must be written EXACTLY as described with lowercase f and uppercase P.

Some of this is probably obvious to those that write scripts.  Very unintuitive.